# Need to find HTML pre tags that contain other tags

Tags: java, regex

I have HTML content with `<pre>` tags that contain other tags. All the angle brackets in the `<pre>` content should be escaped using HTML entities. In other words, every `<` should become `&lt;` and every `>` should become `&gt;`.

For starters, I just want to be able to figure out which files have the offending content. Can anyone think of a way to do this using a regular expression:

**BAD: RegEx should match this**

```
<body>
    <h1>My Content</h1>
    <pre class="some-class">
        <foo>
            <bar>Content</bar>
            <script>
                alert('Hi!');
            </script>
        </foo>
        <br>
    </pre>

    <p>The middle</p>

    <pre class="other-class">
        <bar>
            <foo>Text</foo>
            <script>
                alert('Bye!');
            </script>
        </bar>
        <br>
    </pre>
    <p>The end</p>
</body>
```

**GOOD: RegEx should not match this.**

```
<body>
    <h1>My Content</h1>
    <pre class="some-class">
        &lt;foo&gt;
            &lt;bar&gt;Content&lt;/bar&gt;
            &lt;script&gt;
                alert('Hi!');
            &lt;/script&gt;
        &lt;/foo&gt;
        &lt;br&gt;
    </pre>

    <p>The middle</p>

    <pre class="other-class">
        &lt;bar&gt;
            &lt;foo&gt;Text&lt;/foo&gt;
            &lt;script&gt;
                alert('Bye!');
            &lt;/script&gt;
        &lt;/bar&gt;
        &lt;br&gt;
    </pre>
    <p>The end</p>
</body>
```

Comment: use an HTML Parser not regex

Comment: @Jens Odd .. the half of regex-questions are about parsing HTML/XML .. why people don't want to understand they should use a proper parser instead of regex?

Comment: @Shafizadeh I do not know

Comment: @Jens, thanks. I guess the problem wasn't that I didn't know the answer, it's that I didn't know the question. I'll look into a parser solution. Thanks!

Comment: use parser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

To find the shortest match in a regex use `.*?`.
Also to let the `.` match newline characters, one needs DOT_ALL, `(?s)`.

```
Pattern prePattern = Pattern.compile("(?si)(<pre[^>]*>)(.*?)</pre>");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(html.length() + 1000);
Matcher m = prePattern.matcher(html);
while (m.find()) {
    String text = m.group(2);
    text = text.replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;");
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1) + text + "</pre>");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
html = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks @Joop. That seems close, but the RegEx doesn't work. You can try it at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html. You'll see it matches both the content with the escaped and the unescaped characters.

Comment: It worked in java. The `"(?si)"` (dot-all + case-insensitive) and the eager-evaluation (`*?`) are specific. The replaces where done only inside both pre-formatted sections. Did you try it in java?

Comment: You're right that the replacement part works. It's just that it runs on every pre tag, not just the ones that contains subtags. However, I can use JSoup to just match the pre tags that contain subtags. That combined with your RegEx does the job. So, I'm good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jens and @Joop, I used a solution that combines the JSoup parser and RegEx.

1. Find all <pre> elements that contain child elements:

   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
   Elements badPres = doc.select("pre:has(*)");
2. Loop through those applying @Joop's RegEx solution.